# Best way for Eloquent Model inheritance in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, eloquent, relationship

I have a Laravel project and I'm using Eloquent for models.

Let's say I have three related tables:

```
User
Demographics
Roles
```

I would like my User model to inherit both `Demographics` and `Roles` based on Foreign Key as a one-to-one relation.

I am just looking for some feedback on what might be the most efficient / elegant / safest / performant / cleanest way to accomplish this.

Comment: What do you mean by "Inherit"? How are all the relationships? "best" compared to what?

Comment: In this case, I would prefer composition over inheritance...

Comment: I agree - Traits maybe?

Comment: @DamienPirsy By inherit I mean that when I instantiate my `User` model I would like to see my `Demographics` and `Roles` model properties as well. There is, of course, more than one way to skin this cat, but I am just looking for some feedback on what might be the most efficient / elegant / safest / performant / cleanest ways to accomplish this. I'm updating question to make this a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're just looking for basic relations and eager loading those relations.
Try this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function demographic()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Demographic');
    }
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
    }
}
class Demographic extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
class Role extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Then to access the User with all relations:

```
$user = User::with(['demographic', 'role'])->find(1);

var_dump($user->demographic); // returns the related Demographic model
var_dump($user->role); // returns the related Role model
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the implementation I went with already and have used before. It does seem the cleanest way to handle "eager loading" of relational data in Laravel.